# how to store the data from each loop into an array or table form?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
For[n = 1, n < 6, n = n + 1,
   For[m = 1, m < 6, m = m + 1, abc = doc[[n]];
   kk = doc[[m]];
   v =vector[abc, kk]; 
   vl = VectorLength[v]]]
```

I want to store the data from each loop into an array or table form. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9):

Try using a `Table` instead of two `For` loops.  It returns a list of lists of the results (a matrix basically)

```
Table[
 abc = doc[[n]];
 kk = doc[[m]];
 v = vector[abc, kk];
 vl = VectorLength[v], {n, 1, 5}, {m, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: no you just run this and it returns a list of lists of the results (a matrix basically).

Comment: Thanks @yoda, I did not notice that I had not pasted in the explanatory test in my original answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what data you want to save, but the general way to do this is to use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html).

```
Reap[
  For[n = 1, n < 6, n = n + 1, For[m = 1, m < 6, m = m + 1,
    abc = doc[[n]];
    kk = doc[[m]];
    Sow[v = vector[abc, kk]];
    vl = VectorLength[v]]]
][[2, 1]]
```

This saves every value of `v = vector[abc, kk]`.  The `Part` extraction `[[2, 1]]` returns only this list.

If you want to save multiple data sets, you can use tags within `Sow`:

```
Reap[
 For[n = 1, n < 6, n = n + 1, For[m = 1, m < 6, m = m + 1,
   abc = doc[[n]];
   kk = doc[[m]];
   Sow[v = vector[abc, kk], "v"];
   Sow[vl = VectorLength[v], "v1"]
 ]]
]
```

Here I omit the `Part` extraction.  Output is in the from `{body, {{data1, ...}, {data2, ...}}}` where body is any output from the expression itself (`Null` in the case of For).  Data sets appear in the order they were first sown to.  You can get an explicit order of sets with another argument of `Reap` as follows:

```
Reap[
  For[ ... ],
  {"v1", "v"}
]
```

See the documentation for Reap for more options.