# Create a list of triples to feed in FindFit

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, data-fitting

My goal is to find a 2 parameters fit for a surface. The surface data comes from a txt file and has only height values in it.
So i import it:

```
test = Import["surface.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"]
```

If i read the documentation correctly to use `FindFit`i need to feed in a list or rectangular array containing `{x,y,z}` that is the coordinates of my surface. 
So i try to append to `test` the `x` and `y` which happen to be just integers. 
Following [Advices here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526801/how-to-store-the-data-from-each-loop-into-an-array-or-table-form) instead of using `For` loop i used table to construct a list of triples:

```
test2 = Table[{x, y, test[[x, y]]}, {x, 1, 53}, {y, 1, 34}]
```

However the input is

```
{{{1, 1, -0.174688},....{53,34,-0.0000179476}}}
```

Which seems to indicate that it produced a list of list of triples instead.

As expected doing `fit = Fit[test2, {1, x, y}, {x, y}]` gives a `in Fit is not a list or a rectangular array` error

This is even more likely as `test2` is actually `53*34` so doing `test3 = test2[[1;;34,1;;34]]` would help but i still get the same error which i think comes from the fact i'm still with a list of list of triples, that is, there's one level in excess.

How can i obtain a list of triples?

Comment: `Flatten[Table[...],1]`

Comment: That worked, thanks !

Comment: I think `MapIndexed` is nicer than `Table` for this:
`test2=MapIndexed[Append[#2, #1] &, test, {2}]`

Comment: @Ogamimusashi: There is a dedicated Stack Exchange site for Mathematica where many Wolfram Language experts can help you with your questions! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/